# Error using "Add Table" in Query Designer on created Report Server Project in VS2019

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I right click in Query Designer and select "Add Table..." then get the following error dialog stating: "Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Providers.SqlServer.SqlObjectSupport.xml' was correctly embedded or linked into assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Providers.SqlServer' at compiled time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed."

I am able to use a stored proc but not a table entry.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue on visual studio 2019 version  16.11.1

you can download the fixed file [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Providers.SqlServer.zip](https://aka.ms/dc/file?name=Bca7bb94432284501a611a5e99c16736e637648143331623050_Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Providers.SqlServer.zip&tid=ca7bb94432284501a611a5e99c16736e637648143331623050)
and copy it to:

- Visual Studio 2019 Community

  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE`
- Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise

  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE`

[Original post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Could-not-find-any-resources-appropriate/1505966)

---

***Edit: Fixed in version 16.11.2***